# Django PostgreSQL - the password isn't saved to the database

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I have a custom User model and a function in `views.py` to handle the registration. when I register a user with Postman for example all the user data is stored in the database correctly but the password -field remains empty. I think that causes the problem when I try to use a simple login -page - it never accepts my credentials (because there is no password in the database). Any ideas why the password isn't saved and how to fix it?

I have a function like this in `views.py` when registering a new user:

```
def register(response):

    if response.method == 'POST':

        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save()

            user.refresh_from_db()

            user.id = form.cleaned_data.get('id')

            user.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('email')

            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

            user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)    
    
            return HttpResponse(status=201)



        else:

            form = RegisterForm()

    
    return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

And this is my custom user model:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password):

        """

        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.

        """

        if not email:

            raise ValueError('A user must have a email.')



        user = self.model(

            email=self.normalize_email(email),

        )



        user.set_password(password)

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user
```

Edit. Here is my `RegisterForm`:

```
User = get_user_model()

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password_2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'id', 'gender', 'height', 'weight']

    def clean_email(self):
        '''
        Verify email is available.
        '''
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("email is taken")
        return email 
    
    def clean_id(self):
        '''
        Verify id is available.
        '''
        id = self.cleaned_data.get('id')
        qs = User.objects.filter(id=id)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("id is taken")
        return id

    def clean(self):
        '''
        Verify both passwords match.
        '''
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        password_2 = cleaned_data.get("password_2")
        if password is not None and password != password_2:
            self.add_error("password_2", "Your passwords must match")
        return cleaned_data
```

And here is the model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user

    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser

    gender = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)

    height = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=3)

    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, blank=False, max_length=100)

    email= models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)

    weight = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)    


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # Email & Password are required by default.



    def get_full_name(self):

        # The user is identified by their email address

        return self.email



    def get_short_name(self):

        # The user is identified by their email address

        return self.email



    def __str__(self):

        return self.email



    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):

        "Does the user have a specific permission?"

        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always

        return True



    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):

        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"

        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always

        return True



    @property

    def is_staff(self):

        "Is the user a member of staff?"

        return self.staff



    @property

    def is_admin(self):

        "Is the user a admin member?"

        return self.admin



    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: Share your user model.

Comment: What does `RegisterForm` look like?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited the model into my question.

Comment: @markwalker_ I edited the `RegisterForm ` into my question.

Answer (score 0):

And soon after editing my question I noticed I was missing the save function from the `RegisterForm` class. Adding this solved the problem:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```